# Не могу справится с задачей, математика 10 кл

Tags: математика

> Потолок в аудитории для проведения лабораторных работ подпирают две металлические абсолютно прямые и очень тонкие балки (длина много больше толщины) из ультрасовременного и прочного сплава. Отношение длин этих балок равно kk, а углы, которые балки образуют при этом с полом в аудитории, относятся как 2:3. Найдите наименьшее допустимое значение параметра kk и запишите ответ с точностью до сотой.

Comment: начните с рисунка и запишите равенства/неравенства  которые даны в условии

Answer (score 1):

```
sin(a) = H / L1
sin(b) = H / L2

3a = 2b

L1 * sin(a) / (L2 * sin(b)) = 1
(L1 / L2) * (sin(a) / sin(b)) = 1

sin(b) / sin(a) = k

sin(b) / sin(2/3b) = k

y = sin(x) / sin(2/3x)

через замену, чтоб поудобнее

t = x/3
y = sin(3t) / sin(2t)

y' = - 0.5(2cos(2t) + 3) * tg(t) * cos(t) = 0
t = 0
x = 0

y = sin(3t) / sin(2t) = (3sin(t) - 4sin^2(t)) / (2sin(t)cos(t))
y = 1.5 / cos(t) - 2tg(t)

y(0) = 1.5 / 1 - 2 * 0 = 1.5


k = 1.5
```

хотя с производной можно было бы так и не жестить, а вычислить ее из последней формулы или просто проанализировать поведение y - оно монотонно убывает  :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]